# Установка SSL на IIS сервер

Tags: ssl, iis

После покупки ssl сертификата, мне выдали 3 файла crt. Пытаюсь установить на IIS сервер, собрав все файлы в pfx, но когда пытаюсь импортировать все это дело на сервер, мне пишет что сертификат не содержит закрытого ключа. Что я не так делаю? И есть ли инструкция какая-то подробная. Я все перерыл и не могу найти ответ на вопрос. Есть ответы как устанавливать, но там другие файлы, а что делать с этими тремя файлами crt я не могу понять.
Извините если тупой вопрос, но правда весь гугл перерыл и не нашел ответа.

Comment: `.crt` это просто сертификат, там внутри нет закрытого ключа. Вам нужен приватный ключ, и вам тут никто не подскажет, где его взять. Спрашивайте там, где покупали

Comment: Хорошо, спрошу, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Писал для себя памятку. Выложу её полностью, пока не потерял.
IIS 10, сайт на asp.net core mvc, если это важно

---

**Получение бесплатного сертификата на 3 месяца:**

Сертификат получаем на сайте https://www.sslforfree.com/ используя один из трёх методов.
Я предпочёл метод проверки через файлы в директории *.well-known/acme-challenge/*.

Создать папку удобнее через командную строку. Нажимаем CTR+С вводим cmd, затем в командной строке запоминаем папку расположения и вводим

*md .well-known*
*cd .well-known*
*md acme-challenge*

и переходим в директорию, которую запомнили до этого. Закидываем проверочные файлы в папку acme-challenge и теперь можно закинуть что получилось в корневой каталог сайта.

Открываем IIS и выбираем каталог с проверочными файлами. Щелкаем **Просмотр каталога** в меню справа выбираем **Включить**. Теперь открываем в проводнике папку **acme-challenge** в которой уже должен появиться файл **web.config**. Открываем его и дописываем в соответствующий раздел:

```
<system.webServer>  
    <staticContent>  
        <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/octet-stream" />  
    </staticContent>  
</system.webServer>
```

Теперь все готово к проверке. На https://www.sslforfree.com/ проверяем, что файлы скачиваются и щёлкаем на **Download SSL sertificate**
На следующей страничке скачиваем архив с тремя файлами и ищем в интернете программу [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_1_1d.exe). Она нужна для конвертации этих трёх файлов в один, подходящий для IIS.  После установки находим исполняемый файл openssl.exe у меня это  *C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin* , закидываем к нему все 3 файла из архива, открываем **openssl.exe** и вводим:

```
pkcs12 -export -out "certificate_combined.pfx" -inkey "private.key" -in "certificate.crt" -certfile ca_bundle.crt
```

В папке должен появиться почти готовый к употреблению **certificate_combined.pfx**. 
(Теперь самое время проверить, что порт 443 доступен и проброшен (Брандмауэр, роутер и т.д))

**Добавление сертификата в IIS:**

В IIS на **Начальной странице** открываем **Сертификаты сервера**. В правом верхнем углу выбираем **Импортировать** и добавляем наш сертификат. Далее в настройках сайта добавляем новую привязку, но уже с https и выбираем добавленный ранее сертификат. А в настройках сайта в меню **Параметры SSL** ставим галочку на **Требовать SSL**

Теперь SSL должен работать если вручную вбить https://, но при обращении по http:// может выдать ошибку.
Исправил следуя [инструкции](https://admin812.ru/perenapravlenie-trafika-iis-s-http-na-https.html)